# add colum to merged csv file

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

Ok heres what I have code wise:

```
$a = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\*.csv"
$b = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\merge.csv"

(get-content $a) | set-content $b
```

This pulls all the data of all the files into one merged file, but I need one additional item, I need to pull the name of the individual files and append it to the first column of the file for multiple files, several hundred at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this should do it:

```
$a = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\*.csv"
$b = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\merge.csv"


Get-ChildItem $a | % { 
    Import-Csv $_.Fullname | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'File Name' -Value $_.Name 
} | Export-Csv $b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CSV files each have the same column headings, I would lean toward using `Import-CSV` instead of `Get-Content` so that you can work with the CSV contents as arrays of objects with named properties.

Then all you need to do is iterate through each item of the array and append a property containing the file path, which you can do using the `Add-Member` cmdlet. Once that's done, export the array of objects using the `Export-CSV` cmdlet.

```
$directory = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\"
$search = $directory + "*.csv"
$exportpath = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\merge.csv"
$paths = get-childitem $search
$objectArrays = @()
$paths | %{ 
      $filepath = $_.fullname; 
      $objectArray = Import-CSV $filepath; 
      $objectArray | %{ 
           Add-Member -inputobject $_ -Name "SourceFile" -Value $filepath -MemberType NoteProperty}; 
      $objectArrays += $objectArray}
$objectArrays | export-csv -path $exportpath -notype
```

This puts the SourceFile property as the last column in the outputted CSV file

Comment: If you know the names of the columns, you can set the order in which they appear like so: `$objectArrays | select-object -property SourceFile, Column2, Column3, Column4 | export-csv -path $exportpath -notype`  where "SourceFile" is the name of our file path column, and "Column2" is the name of the column you want in the second column and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simplification... Search target folder, pipe to a `ForEach-Object` loop (shorthand `%` used), capture the file name as variable, import the CSV, add the sourcefile using the `Select-Object` cmdlet, convert it back to a CSV, end loop, pipe to destination file.

```
$a = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\*.csv"
$b = "C:\Users\some.deranged.character\Desktop\SomeAwfulPlace\Checklists\C_F\merge.csv"

GCI $a | %{$FileName=$_.Name;Import-CSV $_|Select @{l='SourceFile';e={$FileName}},*|ConvertTo-CSV -NoType} | set-content $b
```